# Why tf object detection api needs so few pictures?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am wondering why tf object detection api needs so few picture samples for training while regular cnns needs many more?

What I read in tutorials is that tf object detection api needs around 100-500 pictures per class for training (is it true?) while regular CNNs need many many more samples, like tens of thousands or more. Why is it so?

Comment: I haven't work with the tf object detection api so I might be totally wrong but I guess that they need so little data because their models are already trained on huge datasets, and they are just transferring the learning.

Comment: You actually might be right :) haven't thought about it, thanks!

Comment: you are right. Actually from scratch OD needs more images than Classifiers because its a more difficult task

Comment: @razvanc92 you can put your comment as an answer for this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that they need so little data because their models are already trained on huge datasets, and they are just transferring the learning (using those pre-trained models as starting point).